# Conic sections - Hyperbola

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

If we are given a 2 degree curve equation of a hyperbola, is there a way to find the centre, foci, eccentricity and directrices of a hyperbola , just as we can obtain the equation using foci, eccentricity, and directrix? I searched for it, but only found an answer for ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nearly the same equations as you would use for an ellipse.

If you can get it into this form

$\frac {(x-h)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y-v)^2}{b^2} = 1$

then

center: $(h,v)$

vertices are at $(h\pm a, v)$

$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

The eccentricity is $e = \frac {c}{a}$

The foci are at $(h\pm c, v)$
the directrix is at $x= h\pm \frac {a^2}{c}$

if $-\frac {(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-v)^2}{b^2} = 1$

Then some of the equations above will swap $a$ for $b$ and the changes will be happening on a vertical, instead of a horizontal axis.

Comparison to an ellipse

$\frac {(x-h)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-v)^2}{b^2} = 1$

if $a>b$

center: $(h,v)$

vertices: $(h\pm a, v)$

$c = \sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$

eccentricity: $e = \frac {c}{a}$

foci: $(h\pm c, v)$

directrix: $x = h\pm \frac {a^2}{c}$

Comment: Thanks but my problem is converting the 2 degree curve equation into the canonical form you have used above, any thoughts regarding that?

Comment: You asked if formula such as those for an ellipse exist, and indeed they do, and in fact are quite similar in nature.  If you are asking how to manipulate a general quadratic equation into the standard forms of conics, that is a very different question.  And you will need to be more specific regarding what is troubling you and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you please just give me an idea, as I asked formula that can be applied on general quadratic equation not on  standard form

Comment: Have you tried competing the square?